# How to give a hyper link for user name

Tags: php, mysql

[image]In my admin page, admin can view the user id, user name and email id. Now, the admin can click user name, then it displays the details of that particular user name. I don't know how to do. Please help. My code is given below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome
<?php
include ('connect.php');
session_start();
$admin = $_SESSION['adminname'];
echo "$admin";?>
<b><a href="index.php"> SIGN OUT</a></b>
<table border="2" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User_id</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Email ID</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sample");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
      $id=$row[0];
      $name=$row[1];
      $mail=$row[2];

      echo
       "<tr>
            <td>{$row[0]}</td>
            <td>{$row[1]}</td>
            <td>{$row[2]}</td>";
      }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `print_r($row)` and post its value!!

Comment: Hang on, let me get my crystal ball out and divine link for you... Nope, seems it's not working today. I can't seem to get the link to a profile page for your site. You'll have to tell us what the link should be.

Comment: You need to use ajax to fetch record and display it in popup.

Comment: Can i click in the user name field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you query your database to get all username,ID and email.
Then you do a loop to display it.
Key is in your loop you can do like this.

```
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sample");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
         $id=$row[0];
         $name=$row[1];
         $mail=$row[2];

         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>";
         echo "<a href='?userid=$id'>$id</a>";
         echo "</td>"
         echo "<td>";
         echo "<a href='?userid=$id'>$name</a>";
         echo "</td>"
         echo "<td>";
         echo "<a href='?userid=$id'>$email</a>";
         echo "</td>"
         echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```

This is result from loop above.

```
<tr>
    <td>
         <a href='detail.php?userid=1'>Fullname1 : Email1@email.com</a>
         <a href='detail.php?userid=2'>Fullname2 : Email2@email.com</a>
         ...
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now you will see this in your URL `?userid=1`

You can do this on top of detail.php file `$user_id = $_GET['userid'];`

Then you get your user_id // 1 2 3 4 5 ... whatever

Now you do a query again with `$user_id`

like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE user_id = $user_id";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     //do what you want with this user data
}
```

Comment: The above code worked thks @Natsathorn

Answer (score 0):

I here modified your code, Please try this,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome
<?php
include ('connect.php');
session_start();
$admin = $_SESSION['adminname'];
echo "$admin";
?>
<b><a href="index.php"> SIGN OUT</a></b>
<table border="2" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User_id</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Email ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
      $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sample");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
        $id=$row[0];
        $name=$row[1];
        $mail=$row[2];

        echo '<tr>';          
          echo '<td><a href="http://yoursite.com?id=$id">{$row[0]}</a></td>';
          echo '<td><a href="http://yoursite.com?id=$id">{$row[1]}</a></td>';
          echo '<td><a href="http://yoursite.com?id=$id">{$row[2]}</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';          
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: This code doesn't displays any data in user id, name & email id.

Comment: It displays {$row[0]} in all the fields.